# Detect changes made by Firebase SDK in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm currently using AngularFire2 for my project, however, certain functionality such as password change for Auth is not available yet in AngularFire2 so I'm using Firebase SDK to achieve this tasks.

When Firebase SDK triggers any event and some variable is modified, it is not detected immediately by Angular 2, but until a few seconds later (I believe 10 sec)

Is there any way I can detect or watch for changes to variables in my component that were modified by the Firebase SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by importing NgZone:

`import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';`

Declaring it in the constructor:

`constructor (private NgZone: NgZone){}`

And then running this inside my function:

`this.NgZone.run(() => { my code }`